# Sort list in Pyspark using udf and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe where the second column is a list of lists.

Following is the PySpark dataframe that I have:

```
+---+------------------------------+
|A  |B                             |
+---+------------------------------+
|a  |[[95.0], [25.0, 25.0], [40.0]]|
|a  |[[95.0], [20.0, 80.0]]        |
|a  |[[95.0], [25.0, 75.0]]        |
|b  |[[95.0], [25.0, 75.0]]        |
|b  |[[95.0], [12.0, 88.0]]        |
+---+------------------------------+
```

In this example, I am trying to **flatten arrays (in the second column) , sort the arrays and remove the largest element in the ensuing numpy array**.

Following is the output that I expect:

```
+---+------------------------------+
|A  |B                             |
+---+------------------------------+
|a  |[25.0, 25.0, 40.0]            |
|a  |[20.0, 80.0]                  |
|a  |[25.0, 75.0]                  |
|b  |[25.0, 75.0]                  |
|b  |[12.0, 88.0]                  |
+---+------------------------------+
```

Below is the udf that I have at present:

```
def remove_highest(col):
    return np.sort( np.asarray([item for sublist in col for item in sublist])  )[:-1]

udf_remove_highest = F.udf( remove_highest , T.ArrayType() )
```

I get the following error when I try to create this udf:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-6984c2f41293> in <module>()
      2     return np.sort( np.asarray([item for sublist in col for item in sublist])  )[:-1]
      3 
----> 4 udf_remove_highest = F.udf( remove_highest , T.ArrayType() )

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'elementType'
```

**I will like to prefer an udf which uses numpy arrays. How can I achieve the above mentioned aim?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## For your code to work do this:

Numpy array type is not supported as a datatype for spark dataframes, therefore right when when you are returning your transformed array, add a .tolist() to it which will send it as an accepted python list. And add floattype inside of your arraytype

```
def remove_highest(col):
    return (np.sort( np.asarray([item for sublist in col for item in sublist])  )[:-1]).tolist()

udf_remove_highest = F.udf( remove_highest , T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()) )
```

## Most efficient way to do it without udfs. Using higher-order functions:

This will work only for spark 2.4 and above.

Creating your sample dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

list=[['a',[[95.0], [25.0, 25.0], [40.0]]],
      ['a',[[95.0], [20.0, 80.0]]],
      ['a',[[95.0], [25.0, 75.0]]],
      ['b',[[95.0], [25.0, 75.0]]],
      ['b',[[95.0], [12.0, 88.0]]]]

cSchema = StructType([StructField("A", StringType())\
                      ,StructField("B", ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())))])
df= spark.createDataFrame(list,schema=cSchema)
```

Filter expression, with flatten and array_max:

```
expression="""filter(B, x -> x != C )"""
df1=df.withColumn("B",(F.sort_array(F.flatten("B")))).withColumn("C",F.array_max("B")).withColumn("B", F.expr(expression) )\
.drop("C")
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------------------+
|  A|                 B|
+---+------------------+
|  a|[25.0, 25.0, 40.0]|
|  a|      [20.0, 80.0]|
|  a|      [25.0, 75.0]|
|  b|      [25.0, 75.0]|
|  b|      [12.0, 88.0]|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, I think you should mention that some Spark functions above (flatten,  array_max , array_except) only available from Spark2.4.0 (here is reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=explode#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten)

Comment: Thank for the answer. I would love to get the udf (numpy version) working properly. When I used your solution (udf-numpy), I got the following error


```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o129.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 65 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 65.3 in stage 3.0 : net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)
```

Would you know how this can be solved?